# Running a MATLAB .m file from Windows Command prompt and unable to pass strings and numbers as parameters to this script

Tags: python, windows, matlab, parameter-passing, command-prompt

I'm trying to use a MATLAB toolbox for a Python program I'm writing. I've used a system call from Python to run a MATLAB .m script from the Windows Command line and it executes although I'm having trouble passing stings and numbers to the MATLAB script from the command line.

I've looked around to try and find a solution and I found this method but it didn't work

`matlab -r matlabEEGloadfile("String1","String",2,4,55,48)`

- I get an error stating:

> Undefined function 'matlabEEGloadfile' for input arguments of type 'char'.
>   
>   
>   Any help would be appreciated, can't seem to find an answer and I'm sure there's a simple way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: From Python try the `subprocess` module, e.g. `rc = subprocess.call('matlab -r matlabEEGloadfile("String1","String",2,4,55,48)')`.

Comment: Brilliant. That `subprocess` module worked great for me. Also, to any people who are new to MATLAB that are reading this in the future, you need to make sure your .m file is saved in your MATLAB paths otherwise when a new instance of MATLAB is open, MATLAB wont know of the .m file your referencing.